# What is a "vanilla web interface"?

Tags: terminology

Someone told me to look into "vanilla web interface". I have Googled it, but didn't find any relevant result, at least that was I thought. What is it?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The term "vanilla" usually refers to something that's plain and unadorned (from vanilla ice-cream) or perhaps simple (as in basic), so they're asking you to look into a "simple web interface" without any unnecessary complications.

Comment: And they probably mean that it doesn't *rely on* JavaScript, DOM manipulation, and Ajax, just "vanilla" HTML (perhaps with CSS). Not to say you can't have a "vanilla" interface that gets improved if JavaScript and such are available ("progressive/incremental enhancement" aka "graceful degradation").

Answer (score 10):

Considering the [Vanilla software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanilla_software) entry on wikipedia, which states *(quoting)* :

> Vanilla software is computer software
>   that is not customized from its
>   delivered form - i.e. it is used
>   without any customizations applied to
>   it. 
> Vanilla software can become a
>   widespread de facto industry standard,
>   widely used by businesses and
>   individuals.

I'm guessing "Vanilla Web interface" corresponds to the default interface of a web application, not customized or anything.

Answer (score 5):

They mean web 1.0 interface, usually just text and tables, sometimes CSS.