# What is Vanilla CSS and why?

Tags: css

What is Vanilla CSS and why is it called Vanilla CSS? What is the origin of this phrase.

Comment: http://english.stackexchange.com/a/182520

Comment: Yes this should be posted on english.se. But as JJJ mentioned, it's already there. To add to the answer, vanilla is considered plain compared to other flavors like chocolate. So it is used to mean the plain version of something. In this case vanilla css is the basic plain version of css compared to sass or less.

Comment: [Related Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483246/what-is-a-vanilla-web-interface)

Comment: It is so right question. I don't know why people are down voting it. Recently  in a machine test I was allowed to make a web layout with vanilla css and modular css. I really have no idea and needed to search on google for it. This question helped me alot. and it is related to CSS. This should get up vote.

Answer (score 30):

Vanilla CSS is just CSS, vanilla making it absolutely clear that it's CSS and not a superset of it like LESS or SASS (which are also "CSS").

The phrase originally came into existence with the creation of [Less](http://lesscss.org/) in 2010-2011 (judging by the commit logs of https://github.com/less/less.js), to compare and contrast "Vanilla CSS" with "Less CSS".

i.e. It's clearer to say "Less CSS vs Vanilla CSS", compared to "Less CSS vs CSS"

Comment: It's evben clearer to say "LESS vs CSS". And LESS and SASS are not "CSS" - they can be *compiled to CSS*.

Comment: @connexo I would say they have the same amount of clarity. Also I'm not implying LESS is CSS, just saying that some use "CSS" as a blanket term for CSS and all its preprocessors.

Comment: As a funny sidenote, using less css usually results in having more css. ;)

Comment: I hate that "Vanilla" term, why can't people say pure/plain CSS, the same goes for Javascript

Comment: I've also heard «vanilla CSS» being compared to React packages like Styled Components

Answer (score 0):

It’s just a fancy way of saying, "Just plain CSS, no other libraries like Bootstrap"

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32160575)